# Split delimiter based rows in to new rows - SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a following data and I want to split the each row by delimiter into new rows.

Sample Data:

```
**Row No. | Data**
        1 | abc,pqr,lmn,omr
        2 | aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
```

And the output should be:

```
**Row No. | Data**
        1 | abc
        2 | pqr
        3 | lmn
        4 | omr
        5 | aaa
        6 | bbb
        6 | ccc
        6 | ddd
```

I have a following code snippet but it only works for the first row.

```
    SELECT * EXCEPT(c) REPLACE(c AS col) 
    FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
    UNNEST(SPLIT(col)) c;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following:

```sql
WITH myData AS (
  select 
    id, 
    values
    FROM 
      UNNEST([
        STRUCT<id int, values string>(1, 'abc,pqr,lmn,omr'),
        STRUCT<id int, values string>(2, 'aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd')
      ])
)
SELECT 
  id,
  data
FROM myData,
UNNEST(SPLIT(values, ',')) AS data
ORDER BY id ASC
```

I start by just creating a sample temporary table with your test data. The gist of what you're looking for is there at the end. You're on the right track using `UNNEST` to break out the elements of the array out to separate rows, but you were missing the `SPLIT` function to actually break apart the individual values in the string by their comma delimiters.

This query yields the following:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 1 | pqr |
| 1 | lmn |
| 1 | omr |
| 2 | aaa |
| 2 | bbb |
| 2 | ccc |
| 2 | ddd |

And for just a tweak on that - if you simply want a monotonically increasing number as the ID instead of it repeating as it does there (e.g. no need to link back to an ID), update your query to the following:

```sql
WITH myData AS (
  select 
    id, 
    values
    FROM 
      UNNEST([
        STRUCT<id int, values string>(1, 'abc,pqr,lmn,omr'),
        STRUCT<id int, values string>(2, 'aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd')
      ])
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id,
  data
FROM myData,
UNNEST(SPLIT(values, ',')) AS data
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Here I simply dropped use of the `id` field in the SELECT expression and replaced with an incrementing row number that increments over all the records in the data set. This yields the following:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | pqr |
| 3 | lmn |
| 4 | omr |
| 5 | aaa |
| 6 | bbb |
| 7 | ccc |
| 8 | ddd |

Comment: That perfectly works.  I got the idea, it is basically un-nesting the split. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Absolutely - added another example in case you don't need the ID values and just want a row number alongside the values.

Comment: Got it. Appreciate your help!!